# NativeScript tap & longPress together not working

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

On longPress event the tap event also executing

```
<StackLayout (longPress)="onLongPressItem(item)" (tap)="onItemTap(item)">...</StackLayout>
```

is there a way to prevent tap on longPress?
I want to work both events on Same layout.
In ListView we have 'itemTap' only is there a option for 'longPress'?
Please don't suggest me RadListView.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer is still helpful too.  There exists issues concerning your problem:

- https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2823
- https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2977

In the first one, it is described how to manually fix it.  In the second one, a contributor said that they will attempt to fix it in version 3.1.