# Longpress event triggers tap event

Tags: angular, events, nativescript

In a list view I have two events happening, a tap event, and a longpress event, but longpress fires both.
Inside the .html file:

```
<ListView class="listViewContainer" [items]="contactList">
  <ng-template let-item="item" let-i="index">
   <StackLayout 
    (loaded)="loaded($event)"
    orientation="horizontal"
    class="preview-info-container"
   >
   </StackLayout>
  </ng-template>
</ListView>
```

And then the .ts file

```
loaded(args) {
const element = args.object;
element.on("loaded, tap, longPress", (args) => {
  // console.log("Event: " + args.eventName + ", sender: " + args.object);
    if(args.eventName === "tap") {
      this.router.navigate(["card/contact/" + this.contact.id]);
    } else {
      this.togglePreviewOptions = !this.togglePreviewOptions;
    }
  });
}
```

My question is, how can I prevent the tap event from being fired when long pressing on the specific field?

This might be duplicate issue of [NativeScript tap & longPress together not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42228969/7329285), however since there has not been a clear answer I would like to raise it again.

**Edit**
Some more info:
The project tns version is

```
$ tns --version 4.3.0-2018-08-31-12160
```

Global nativescript version

```
nativescript@4.3.0-2018-08-31-12160
```

Emulator version:

```
Iphone 6, iOS 11.3
```

Comment: Elaborate your question.

Comment: I have edited with a more specific question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not been able to solve this issue by adding two different events (tap/longPress). 
As a solution i use the following

Inside `.html`

```
   <StackLayout (touch)="onTouch($event)">
      <Contact-Preview [contact]=contactList[i]></Contact-Preview>
   </StackLayout>
```

Inside `.ts`

```
onTouch(args: TouchGestureEventData) {
  if(args.action === "down") {
    this.start = new Date().getMilliseconds();
  }
  if(args.action === "up") {
    this.end = new Date().getMilliseconds();
    const duration = Math.abs(this.start - this.end)
    console.log(duration > 150? "long press": "tap")
  }
}
```

This prevents tap and longPress events being fired on the same time, thus working around my issue.

Comment: Thanks so much for figuring this out. This is my preferred solution now, instead of the longPress event.

Answer (score 3):

We also had the issue that both events were triggered on iOS.
Based on @GeorgeK's answer I wrapped his method in a service.
I also made sure you can press multiple items at once by using an item identifier. I also added a handler for the cancel and move action to prevent selecting items while scrolling:

touch-event.service.ts:

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { TouchGestureEventData } from "tns-core-modules/ui/gestures";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root"
})
export class TouchEventService {

    static longPressTimeout: number = 500;
    private events: Map<string, number> = new Map<string, number>();
    private startY: Map<string, number> = new Map<string, number>();
    private startX: Map<string, number> = new Map<string, number>();

    constructor() {
    }

    onTouch(args: TouchGestureEventData, id: string, item: any, itemTapCallback?: (item: any) => any, longPressCallback?: (item: any) => any) {
        if (args.action === "down") {
            // When someone starts pressing the element.
            // Create a new timeout that will trigger the long press callback
            // after longPressTimeout.
            this.startX.set(id, args.getX());
            this.startY.set(id, args.getY());
            // @ts-ignore
            this.events.set(id, setTimeout(() => {
                this.clearItem(id);
                longPressCallback(item);
            }, TouchEventService.longPressTimeout));
        } else if (args.action === "up" && this.events.has(id)) {
            // When someone stops pressing the element.
            // If we have an existing event, this means the long press did
            // not trigger yet. Remove the timeout and trigger the tap callback.
            clearTimeout(this.events.get(id));
            this.clearItem(id);
            itemTapCallback(item);
        } else if (args.action === "cancel" && this.events.has(id)) {
            // When someone moves away from the element while pressing.
            // Prevents handlers to be called while scrolling.
            clearTimeout(this.events.get(id));
            this.clearItem(id);
        } else if (args.action === "move" && this.events.has(id)) {
            // When someone moves from the element while pressing.
            // Prevents handlers to be called while scrolling.
            // This is mainly for iOS because they do not trigger cancel
            // when scrolling out of view. But also useful for large items.
            const differenceX = Math.abs(args.getX() - this.startX.get(id));
            const differenceY = Math.abs(args.getY() - this.startY.get(id));
            if (differenceX > 30 || differenceY > 10) {
                clearTimeout(this.events.get(id));
                this.clearItem(id);
            }
        }
    }

    clearItem(id: string) {
        this.events.delete(id);
        this.startX.delete(id);
        this.startY.delete(id);
    }
}
```

Here's an example of how to implement it in a component:
example.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { TouchEventService } from "./touch-event.service";

@Component({
    selector: "Example",
    templateUrl: "./example.component.html"
})
export class ExampleComponent {
    private _itemTapHandler: (item: any) => any;
    private _longPressHandler: (item: any) => any;

    constructor(public touchEventService: TouchEventService) {
        this._itemTapHandler = this.itemTapHandler();
        this._longPressHandler = this.longPressHandler();
    }

    itemTapHandler(): (item: any) => any {
        return (item) => {
            return this.itemTap(item);
        };
    }

    longPressHandler(): (item: any) => any {
        return (item) => {
            return this.longPress(item);
        };
    }

    itemTap(item: any) {
        // Handle the item tap here.
    }

    longPress(item: any) {
        // Handle the long press here.
    }
}
```

example.component.html

```html
<StackLayout *ngFor="let item of items" (touch)="touchEventService.onTouch($event, item.id, item, _itemTapHandler, _longPressHandler)">
    <!-- Your item content here, you can use the touch in anything, like list views and scroll views -->
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be much easier for you to define 2 events in your template code:

```
<ListView class="listViewContainer" [items]="contactList">
  <ng-template let-item="item" let-i="index">
   <StackLayout 
    (loaded)="loaded($event)"

    (tap)="functionWhenTap(item)" 
    (longPress)="functionWhenLongPress(item)" 

    orientation="horizontal"
    class="preview-info-container"
   >
   </StackLayout>
  </ng-template>
</ListView>
```

and then, handle it in your `.ts` file with these:

```
  functionWhenTap(item: any) {
    // your things to do when tapped
  }

  functionWhenLongPress(item: any) {
    // your things to do when long pressed
  }
```

This is an actual piece of code. Should work for you as well.

Here's working example, tested on my physical personal device:
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=XgBfFE

Comment: Thanks for your comment!
I have tried this way, but i cannot prevent the tap event from being triggered at the end of the long press, thus when i console log i get two"longpressed" events, and then "tapped"

Comment: Well, that's interesting. Have you tried clearing your env. A little bit? Like, quit your emulator, remove `node_modules`, `hooks` and `platforms`, then `npm i` and `tns platform add ios/android`? Maybe something is cached. Maybe some `tns build android/ios --clear`? Start with these and we'll see.

Comment: And why the heck there are 2x long presses and 1x tap? Hmm.

Comment: Removed node_modules, hooks, and platform, and still getting exactly the same issue. Longpress is fired twice in the beginning and then tap is fired once.

Comment: What version of {N} do you use?

Comment: $ tns --version
4.3.0-2018-08-31-12160

Comment: And does your global nativescript version match? (`npm ls -g --depth=0`) have you tried running on physical device?

Comment: This is the global version: nativescript@4.3.0-2018-08-31-12160
I have not tried running on a device yet.

Comment: And what's you emulator device API version?

Comment: it is an Iphone 6 with iOS 11.3

Comment: Have you tried defining tap event one level higher - on ListView instead of it's child? I believe there's something like `(itemTapped)` if I recall well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183448/discussion-between-ogrodowiczp-and-georgek).

Answer (score 1):

More clear is to use the directive:

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Output, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";
import { TouchAction, TouchGestureEventData } from "@nativescript/core";

@Directive({
    selector: "[press], [pressHold]",
})
export class PressDirective {
    @Output() press: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter();
    @Output() pressHold: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter();

    private readonly pressHoldTimeout: number = 500;
    private _startPress: number;
    private _timeout: NodeJS.Timeout;
    private _cancel: boolean;

    @HostListener("touch", ["$event"])
    touch(event: TouchGestureEventData) {
        switch (event.action) {
            case TouchAction.down:
                this._cancel = false;
                this._startPress = Date.now();
                this._timeout = setTimeout(() => {
                    this.pressHold.emit();
                }, this.pressHoldTimeout);

                break;

            case TouchAction.up:
                if (
                    !this._cancel &&
                    Date.now() - this._startPress < this.pressHoldTimeout
                ) {
                    clearTimeout(this._timeout);
                    this.press.emit();
                }
                break;

            case TouchAction.move:
            case TouchAction.cancel:
                clearTimeout(this._timeout);
                this._cancel = true;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

In template:`enter code here`

```
<Button
  (press)="onPress()"
  (pressHold)="onPressHold()"
  text="press && hold"
>
</Button>
```